# Why can't I read everything in my field of view?

Tags: vision, human-eye

When I look at a piece of text, I can *see* all the text on the paper, no matter where I look, because my field of view covers it all. However, if I stare at a specific word, I cannot read the text a few lines above the position I am staring at, even though I can clearly see there is text there. I don't think it has anything to do with the text being out of focus, since I observe this phenomenon no matter what distance the paper is from me. What are the specific causes of this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The field of view is determined by the light-receptive parts of the eye: the *retinae* [(Kolb, 2012)](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-i-foundations/simple-anatomy-of-the-retina/). The fovea is the region with the highest resolution. It is located in the central part of the retina and covers only about 2 degrees of the field of view [(Lauweryns, 2012)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NrirB_KZ4uoC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=foveal%20vision%20degrees&source=bl&ots=eyxRSGm7jA&sig=vJw_S6cNyLLMr8bS33EcAn_Sf1o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYm42h0-jJAhUFmw4KHY--AbEQ6AEIgwEwFQ#v=onepage&q=foveal%20vision%20degrees&f=false). The [total field of view](http://www.clarkvision.com/articles/eye-resolution.html) is roughly 180<sup>o</sup> (Fig. 1).

[image: fov and acuity]
<sup>Fig. 1. Schematic of the human field of view showing the foveal region. Source: [Medical Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/acuity).</sup>

The reason for the regional differences in retinal resolution (referred to as **[visual acuity](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003396.htm)**) is that the cone photoreceptors are densely packed in the foveal region, while rod photoreceptors predominate the retina outside the fovea region (Fig. 2) [(Kolb, 2012)](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-i-foundations/simple-anatomy-of-the-retina/).

[image]
<sup>Fig. 2. Distribution of rods and cones. Source: [Webvision](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-xiii-facts-and-figures-concerning-the-human-retina/).</sup>

The cones sense color and are specialized to work under well-lighted (photopic) conditions. In contrast, rods are hardwired to converge onto a single optic fiber to collect responses for dim lighting (scotopic, or night vision). Because many rods (tens of rods) connect to a single optic nerve fiber, the spatial acuity is dramatically reduced (Fig. 3). Hence, you can read with only a few degrees of your vision. While reading, your eyes continuously scan the page for the next word to center it onto the foveal region.

[image: rod & cone wiring]
<sup>Fig. 3. Many rods converge onto a single ganglion cell, while one cone synapses onto a single ganglion cell. Source: [Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/dominic54/chapter-3-neurons-and-perception).</sup>

This is the big handicap that people with [age-related macular degeneration](https://nei.nih.gov/health/maculardegen/armd_facts) face. The macula (that includes the foveal region, see Fig. 1) degenerates and the cones are lost. Hence, they loose their high-acuity region and cannot read anymore without using magnifiers or other low vision aids.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Kolb, Webvision - The Organization of the Retina and Visual System (2012)](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-i-foundations/simple-anatomy-of-the-retina/)

**-** [Lauweryns, Brain and the Gaze: On the Active Boundaries of Vision (2012)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NrirB_KZ4uoC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=foveal%20vision%20degrees&source=bl&ots=eyxRSGm7jA&sig=vJw_S6cNyLLMr8bS33EcAn_Sf1o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYm42h0-jJAhUFmw4KHY--AbEQ6AEIgwEwFQ#v=onepage&q=foveal%20vision%20degrees&f=false)</sub>